# problem in Nmap while using sudo

Tags: linux, nmap

Recently I had a problem, each time using `sudo` for `nmap` with `--spoof-mac` gives me an output that the host is down, which actually is not right because I know it is up.

Why is that happening?

Giving here an example to what happened when I sent this command on the terminal:

```
$ sudo nmap --spoof-mac Apple  192.168.1.1 -Pn
Host discovery disabled (-Pn). All addresses will be marked 'up' and scan times will be slower.
Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-01-02 05:12 CST
Spoofing MAC address 00:03:93:03:E5:58 (Apple)
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 1.68 seconds
```

Comment: All it is saying is that it can not prove that it is up (no services found). What services are you expecting to be running on the address?

Comment: If you drop `--sppof-mac`, you get a different output?

Comment: The bigger question is, what do you expect in particular by using `--spoof-mac` ?

Comment: On superuser https://superuser.com/questions/887887/different-behavior-sudo-nmap-vs-just-nmap